ICollection cannot be used for parameter of type IList of method PopulateList
I have modified my EF core entities, to swap out all Lists for ICollections, to adhere to my new code linter rules. So why can't I do this anymore:
var allVgnItms1 = context.VgnItms.ToList();

without it throwing:

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in
System.Linq.Expressions.dll: 'Expression of type
'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection1[System.Int32]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList1[System.Int32]' of method
'System.Collections.Generic.IList1[System.Int32] PopulateList[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IList1[System.Int32],
System.Collections.Generic.IList1[System.Int32])''    at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)    at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(MethodInfo method, Expression arg0, Expression arg1)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.<AddInitializeExpressions>g__CreateMemberAssignment|14_0(Expression parameter, MemberInfo memberInfo, IPropertyBase property, Expression value)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.AddInitializeExpressions(HashSet1
properties, ParameterBindingInfo bindingInfo, Expression
instanceVariable, List1 blockExpressions)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.CreateMaterializeExpression(List1
blockExpressions, ParameterExpression instanceVariable, Expression
constructorExpression, HashSet1 properties, ParameterBindingInfo bindingInfo)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.CreateMaterializeExpression(EntityMaterializerSourceParameters parameters, Expression materializationContextExpression)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.EntityMaterializerInjectingExpressionVisitor.CreateFullMaterializeExpression(ITypeBase concreteTypeBase, ValueTuple4 materializeExpressionContext)    at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.EntityMaterializerInjectingExpressionVisitor.MaterializeEntity(StructuralTypeShaperExpression
shaper, ParameterExpression materializationContextVariable,
ParameterExpression concreteEntityTypeVariable, ParameterExpression
instanceVariable, ParameterExpression entryVariable)    at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.EntityMaterializerInjectingExpressionVisitor.ProcessEntityShaper(StructuralTypeShaperExpression
shaper)    at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.EntityMaterializerInjectingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression
extensionExpression)    at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.EntityMaterializerInjectingExpressionVisitor.Inject(Expression
expression)    at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.InjectEntityMaterializers(Expression
expression)    at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression
extensionExpression)    at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.ProcessShaper(Expression
shaperExpression, RelationalCommandCache& relationalCommandCache,
IReadOnlyList1& readerColumns, LambdaExpression& relatedDataLoaders, Int32& collectionId)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitShapedQuery(ShapedQueryExpression shapedQueryExpression)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_01.b__0()
at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object
cacheKey, Func1 compiler)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable1.GetEnumerator()
at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator() at System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection)   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)    at
Vepo.Infrastructure.VgnItmsSearchIndexService`2.ReIndexVgnItms(VpDbContext
context) in
/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_back_end/Vepo.Infrastructure/Search/VgnItmsSearchIndexService/VgnItmsSearchIndexService.cs:line
59

if my VgnItm has ICollection fields. But if I change the ICollections to Lists, the code above works. context.VgnItms is a DbSet<VgnItm>. I can't see any documentation suggesting ICollection doesn't behave well with EF Core entities when performing DbSet queries.
This is my VgnItm class. But essentially if I swap out all the ICollections for Lists, the code above runs fine:
namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public class VgnItm : CreatedBySomeone
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(3000)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(900)]
        public string WebPage { get; set; }

        public string Instagram { get; set; }
        public string Facebook { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int IsNotVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;

        [Required]
        public int IsVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;

        [Required]
        public int RatingsCount { get; set; } = 0;

        public double? Rating { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        private ICollection<int> _tags = new Collection<int>();

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("tags")]
        public ICollection<int> Tags
        {
            get => _tags;
            set => _tags = value;
        }

        [JsonIgnore]
        private ICollection<int> _secondaryTags = new Collection<int>();

#nullable enable
        [JsonPropertyName("secondaryTags")]
        public ICollection<int>? SecondaryTags
        {
            get => _secondaryTags;
            set => _secondaryTags = value;
        }

        public int? PricePoint { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(20)]
        [JsonIgnore]
        private ICollection<Image> _images = new Collection<Image>();

        [JsonPropertyName("images")]
        public ICollection<Image> Images
        {
            get => _images;
            set => _images = value;
        }

        public string Discriminator { get; set; }

        public void UpdateTags(IEnumerable<int> tags)
        {
            _tags = new Collection<int>(tags.ToList());
        }

        public void UpdateSecondaryTags(IEnumerable<int> secondaryTags)
        {
            _secondaryTags = new Collection<int>(secondaryTags.ToList());
        }

        public void UpdateImages(IEnumerable<Image> images)
        {
            _images = new Collection<Image>(images.ToList());
        }
    }
}

Potentially relevant parts of VepoContext.cs (entity configuration):
namespace Vepo.DataContext
{
    public class VpDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public VpDbContext(DbContextOptions<VpDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

        public string _currentUserExternalId;

        public async Task<int> SaveUserAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var user = await User.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == _currentUserExternalId);

            if (user != null)
            {
                AddCreatedByOrUpdatedBy(user);
            }

            return (await base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken));
        }

        public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var user = await User.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == _currentUserExternalId);

            if (user != null)
            {

                AddCreatedByOrUpdatedBy(user);
                Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            }

            return (await base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken));
        }

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            var user = User.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == _currentUserExternalId);
            AddCreatedByOrUpdatedBy(user);
            if (user != null)
            {
                Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            }

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void AddCreatedByOrUpdatedBy(User user)
        {
            foreach (var changedEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                if (changedEntity.Entity is CreatedBySomeone entity)
                {
                    switch (changedEntity.State)
                    {
                        case EntityState.Added:
                            entity.CreatedBy = user;
                            entity.UpdatedBy = user;
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Modified:
                            Entry(entity).Reference(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                            entity.UpdatedBy = user;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("postgis");

            // Metadata

            foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
                .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string)))
            {
                if (property.GetMaxLength() == null)
                    property.SetMaxLength(256);
            }

            foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
                .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(System.DateTime)))
            {
                property.SetColumnType("timestamp");
            }

            foreach (var et in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                foreach (var prop in et.GetProperties())
                {
                    if (prop.Name == "CreatedDate" || prop.Name == "UpdatedDate")
                    {
                        prop.ValueGenerated = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate;
                    }
                }
            }

            // VgnItms

            modelBuilder.Entity<VgnItm>(vgnItm =>
            {
                vgnItm.HasIndex("CompanyName", "Name", "Discriminator").IsUnique();
                vgnItm.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
                vgnItm.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
                vgnItm.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
                vgnItm.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
                vgnItm.HasKey(e => e.Id);
                vgnItm.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
                vgnItm.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
                vgnItm.HasMany(e => e.Images)
                    .WithOne();
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeItm>(recipeItm =>
            {
                recipeItm.Property(e => e.Ingredients).HasColumnType("jsonb");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<SingleLocationVgnItm>(singleLocationVgnItm =>
            {
                singleLocationVgnItm.HasIndex("CompanyName", "Name", "Discriminator", "LocationId").IsUnique();
                singleLocationVgnItm
                .HasOne(s => s.Location) // Each SingleLocationVgnItm has one Location.
                .WithMany() // A Location can be associated with many SingleLocationVgnItm.
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.LocationId); // Foreign key in SingleLocationVgnItm pointing to Location.
            });

        public DbSet<VgnItm> VgnItms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GroceryItm> GroceryItms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EventItm> EventItms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FashionItm> FashionItms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RecipeItm> RecipeItms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GroceryStoreItm> GroceryStoreItms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RestaurantItm> RestaurantItms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MenuItm> MenuItms { get; set; }
    }
}

The issue doesn't happen when removing ToList() from var allVgnItms1 = context.VgnItms.ToList();
The issue doesn't happen if all of the array fields are declared like this:
    [JsonIgnore]
    private IList<int> _tags = new List<int>();

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("tags")]
    public IList<int> Tags
    {
        get => _tags;
        set => _tags = value;
    }

The issue doesn't happen if all of the array fields are declared like this:
    [JsonIgnore]
    private Collection<int> _tags = new Collection<int>();

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("tags")]
    public Collection<int> Tags
    {
        get => _tags;
        set => _tags = value;
    }

The issue does happen if all of the array fields are declared like this:
    [JsonIgnore]
    private ICollection<int> _tags = new Collection<int>();

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("tags")]
    public ICollection<int> Tags
    {
        get => _tags;
        set => _tags = value;
    }

The issue does happen if all of the array fields are declared like this:
    [JsonIgnore]
    private IEnumerable<int> _tags = new List<int>();

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("tags")]
    public IEnumerable<int> Tags
    {
        get => _tags;
        set => _tags = value;
    }


That might be one of the most complex entity classes I have ever seen. For a start I think you are mixing up domain classes with those typically used for Entity Framework. EF objects should really contain properties and nothing else.

@DavidG I know. Off topic of the question. ICollection used with DBSet queries for now please. The entity only began having methods to support ICollection. It was just the field as a List before.

The problem is that it's now very hard to extract which part of your project is actually causing the error. you also haven't shown the EF context or entity configuration if there is some. BEcause this code as it stands looks OK apart from the extra, unnecessary stuff you have here.

@DavidG The methods are just setting the properties. If I change the fields back to Lists there are no methods at all. The rest of the extra is only attributes, I have not heard of attributes causing these types of issue but I can remove them if you think they are. The issue is happening in PopulateList() which is happening somewhere within ToList(). I have added more configuration code and different variations of array types that work and others that don't work.

@DavidG The methods shouldn't be causing the issue because IList, List and Collection work when the methods are left in.
